# How to make a nav HREF load the link differently depending on browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

UPDATE : I Suppose a better way to describe it is i want the link to load a different page depending on screen size so if on desktop it loads page1.html when clicked and if on mobile it loads page2.html when clicked.

So im at a loss with this one, I have a nav bar on my website and on that is the word "forum" when you click forum it loads a lytebox and the forum loads within that, now that is great for laptops or desktops, but doesn't load so well with mobiles, so what I wanted to know... is it possible to add any script that says if the user is using a mobile phone or a screen res that is small, that it opens the link as a new page rather than using the lytebox.

I'll add my nav code below so you can see the current set up.

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
    <ul class="nav" id="top-navigation">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a>    </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="showRight">TS Viewer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#price">Servers</a></li>
        <li><a href="squad.html">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.myforum.com/example" rel="lyteframe" title="IRU" rev="width:100%; height:100%; scrolling: no;">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#donate">Donate</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you can make two links with different classes and show/hide them in a css rule inside a media query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: No its not, so please dont vote down....

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nav a").click(function(){
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width()<=768){
        //mobile
    }
    else{
        //pc
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, could you share how i would intergrate that with my nav forum section so -

'<li><a href="http://www.myforum.com/example" rel="lyteframe" title="IRU" rev="width:100%; height:100%; scrolling: no;">Forum</a></li>'

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to detect if the user is using a mobile browser. Quick reference [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

```js
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

and make a script at the end of your page something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.mobilecheck === true) {
    $('a#yourid').removeProp('rel');
  }
</script>
```

This uses jQuery but can be done in javascript also it removes the `rel` attribute which is used by the lytebox, but can also be done in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<li><a href="myforum.com/example" rel="lyteframe" title="IRU" rev="width:100%; height:100%; scrolling: no;">Forum</a></li>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.mobile-links,[rel="lyteframe"]').click(function(e) {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).removeProp('rel');
            location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Andres thanks for helping, could you possible show me how i would work this using the code that i provided, this line in particular as it loads the lytebox when on desktop - 

`<li><a href="myforum.com/example"; rel="lyteframe" title="IRU" rev="width:100%; height:100%; scrolling: no;">Forum</a></li>`

Comment: Already edited. Could you test it? I have improved the code, so you don't need to add any class to the elements. Now works when the element has the property rel="lyteframe" or the class "mobile-links".

Comment: Thanks Andrews, just tested it, it still loads the forum in the lytebox, what i want is that if im on a mobile that is does not use lyte box, so lyte for pc but the forum loads as separate page if on mobile., thanks for your help.

Comment: I have just edited my example, try it again. How is lytebox triggered? Through a class, "rel" property..? Maybe it has another attached event to the element 'a' or 'li' which prevent the code to execute properly